# Java Design: dealing with data objects used by many classes

Tags: java, data-objects

First, a brief description of the library that brought this up:

I have a library that listens continuously on a provided serial port, reading in blocks of bytes and passing them along to be processed in some meaningful way (details aren't important to the question).  To make the library a bit more reusable, processing these bytes was abstracted out to an interface (FrameProcessor).  A few default implementations exist in the library itself to handle processing that's always going to occur regardless of the application using it.  However, there's support for adding in custom processors to do things the application specifically cares about.

Aside from the bytes being passed to these processors, there's a data object (ReceiverData) that contains information that most (but not guaranteed to be all) of the processors might find interesting.  It's maintained entirely by the library itself (i.e. it isn't the responsibility of the application to setup/maintain any instances of ReceiverData.  They shouldn't have to care how the data is made available, just that it is available).

Right now, ReceiverData is being passed as a parameter to each processor:

```
public interface FrameProcessor {

    public boolean process(byte[] frame, ReceiverData receiverData);
}
```

However, I really don't like this approach, as it's requiring data to be passed to something that might not necessarily care about it.  Also, for the processors that do care about ReceiverData, they've got to pass the object reference around in whatever other method calls they make (provided those method calls need to access that data).

I've considered changing the FrameProcessor to an abstract class and then defining a setter for a protected ReceiverData member.  But that seems kind of gross as well - having to iterate over the list of all FrameProcessors and setting the ReceiverData instance.

I've also thought about some kind of static threaded context object(necessarily threaded since the library supports listening on multiple ports at once).  Essentially, you'd have something like the following:

```
public class ThreadedContext {

    private static Map<Long, ReceiverData> receiverData;

    static {
        receiverData = new HashMap<Long, ReceiverData>();
    }

    public static ReceiverData get() {
        return receiverData.get(Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    public static void put(ReceiverData data) {
        receiverData.put(Thread.currentThread().getId(), data);
    }
}
```

That way, when each thread in the library started, it could just add a reference to its ReceiverData to ThreadedContext, which would then be available as needed to the processors without needing to pass it around.

This is certainly a pedantic question, as I've already got a solution that works fine.  It just bothered me.  Thoughts?  Better approaches?

Comment: I like the `ThreadedContext` approach best. FYI, there is `java.lang.ThreadLocal<T>` you can use instead of the `HashMap` with thread ids as keys.

Comment: Could you give more details on what ReceiverData actually does and contains. It sounds to me that it should be a member of some FrameProcessor subclasses, but it's hard to say without more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like your current approach the best. It's inherently thread-safe (because stateless). It allows for the same processor to be used by multiple threads. It's easy to understand and use. It's very similar to, for example, the way a servlet works: the request and the response objects are passed to the servlet, even if they don't care about them. And it's also very easy to unit test, because you don't have to setup a thread-local context to be able to test a processor. You just pass a ReceiverData (real or fake), and that's it.

You could, instead of passing a byte array and a ReceiverData, mix both in a single argument.

Comment: The request/response objects are actually some of the things considered wrong with the servlet design (see [here](http://misko.hevery.com/2009/04/08/how-to-do-everything-wrong-with-servlets/), for example); kitchen-sink objects, service-locator anti-pattern...

Comment: Well, they're considered wrong by this particular blogger. And the kitchen sink and service locator problems don't apply here, since the ReceiverData is a simple data object. I agree that servlets are hard to test. But putting state in a thread-local is much worse than injecting state in a method argument regarding testability.

Comment: I ended up sticking with just passing the ReceiverData object to the various processors.  I hadn't been weighing your point on ease of understanding very highly, but, thinking about it, this is a library that we're hoping is going to be used by many applications, so understanding how it works is extremely important.  Ease of testing is a nice perk as well.  Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate the `byte[]` and `ReceiverData` into a new class and pass that to the frame processors. Not only does it mean they can pass the same, single object around to their own methods, but it allows for future expansion if necessary.

```
public class Frame {
    private byte[] rawBytes;
    private ReceiverData receiverData;

    public ReceiverData getReceiverData() { return receiverData; }
    public byte[] getRawBytes() { return frame; }
}

public interface FrameProcessor {
    public boolean process(Frame frame);
}
```

While this may seem like overkill and require the processors to make unnecessary method calls, you may find that you don't want to provide access to the raw byte array. Perhaps you want to use a `ByteChannel` instead and provide read-only access. It depends on your library and how it's intended to be used, but you may find you can provide a nicer API inside `Frame` than a simple byte array.

Comment: This seems like the most natural way of solving the problem. The bytes and the ReceiverData always go together, so put them together. It does make the data slightly harder to get to (`frame.getRawBytes()` rather than `frame`), but not substantially so.

Answer (score 0):

As the OP states, the problem with `process(byte[] frame, ReceiverData data)` is that `ReceiverData` may or may not be used by the implementation. Thus, it is "wrong" that `process()` has a dependency on `ReceiverData`. Instead, a `FrameProcessor` implementation should use a `Provider` that can provide the instance of `ReceiverData` for the current frame on-demand.

The example below illustrates this. I've used dependency injection for clarity, but you can just as well pass those objects in the constructors. The `FrameContext` would use `ThreadLocal<T>`s, much like suggested in the OP. See [this link](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomScopes) for implementation hints. A DIY `Provider<T>` implementation would likely depend on `FrameContext` directly.

If you want to go this route, consider using a DI-framework such as [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) or [CDI](http://seamframework.org/Weld). Guice is probably easier when working with custom scopes.

```
public class MyProcessor implements FrameProcessor {

    @Inject
    private Provider<ReceiverData> dataProvider;

    public boolean process(byte[] frame) {
        ...
        ReceiverData data = dataProvider.get();
        ...
    }
}

public class Main {

    @Inject
    private FrameContext context;

    public void receiveFrame(byte[] frame, ... ) {

        context.begin();
        ...
        context.setReceiverData(...); // receiver data is thread-local
        ...

        for (FrameProcessor processor : processors)
            processor.process(frame);

        context.end();
    }
}
```

This approach is very extensible; future needed objects can be added to the context/scope object and corresponding providers injected into processors:

```
public class MyProcessor ... {

    @Inject private Provider<FrameMetaData>;
    @Inject private Provider<FrameSource>;
    ...
}
```

As you can see from this example, this approach will also allow you to avoid future situations where you would add "sub-objects" to `ReceiverData`, leading to a kitchen-sink object situation (for example, `ReceiverData.metaData`, `ReceiverData.frameSource`, ... ).

**Note:** Ideally, you'd have processing objects with a lifetime equal to a single frame. Then you could just declare (and inject!) the dependencies for processing a single frame in the constructor and create a new processor for each frame. But I assume you are processing a lot of frames and therefore want to stick with the current approach for performance reasons.